# Where is the best place for the back button?

Tags: buttons, placement, back-button, position

In some apps, you need to go through a number of steps. Of course, a back button is needed in this process, in case the user has made a mistake or changes his mind.

But my question is, what is the best place for this back button?

Since the top left is pretty standard for most apps, this makes it recognizable for the user and therefore easier to find and use. This position is only difficult to reach for mobile devices.

That is why the bottom left would also be possible, but the most important option like a next button is at the bottom. In addition, it is also important that the back button is in the same position throughout the app.

What is your vision?

Comment: Typing "place back button" in the search field at the top, you'll find several questions/answers about the same topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've 2 options.

The first one is like when you fill a form or a stepper, and you need to navigate from page to page to fill in informations. Having a back & next button in bottom of the page makes sense, because it makes it easy to navigate the steps.

The second one is like when you've a folder navigation. Which means you enter a page/ folder, and to go back you've a back button or arrow at the top.